# Easy way to add combination of tags, text and links in Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looking to scrape references off a website and appending them to my pre-existing list of references, so far I've been successful with scraping, but I can't seem to do the final step which is appending to the existing references. Let me illustrate:

The reference I managed to scrape:

```
scraped_ref = 'Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, <a href="https://radiopaedia.org/">Radiopaedia.org</a>. From the case <a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52525">rID: 52525</a> [Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].'
```

I need to add the following tag before that reference:

```
<br>3. <b>Image: </b>
```

Which will then make it:

```
formatted_ref = '<br>3. <b>Image: </b>Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, <a href="https://radiopaedia.org/">Radiopaedia.org</a>. From the case <a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52525">rID: 52525</a> [Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].'
```

Then finally add the formatted reference to my pre-existing list of references:

```
existing_ref = <p class="references" style="font-size:15px">1. Mcminn. (2003). Last's Anatomy. Elsevier Australia. ISBN:0729537528. <a href="http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0729537528">Read it at Google Books</a> - <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0729537528">Find it at Amazon</a><br>2. Netter, F. H. (2019). Atlas of human anatomy. Philadelphia, PA: Elsevier.</p>
```

I tried this:

```
for p in soup.find_all("p", {"class":"references"}):
    print(p.append('<br>3. <b>Image: </b>' + scraped_ref))
```

But the result I got lost all tag information:

```
<p class="references" style="font-size:15px">1. Mcminn. (2003). Last's Anatomy. Elsevier Australia. ISBN:0729537528. <a href="http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0729537528">Read it at Google Books</a> - <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0729537528">Find it at Amazon</a><br/>
2. Netter, F. H. (2019). Atlas of human anatomy. Philadelphia, PA: Elsevier.&lt;br&gt;3. &lt;b&gt;Image: &lt;/b&gt;Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/"&gt;Radiopaedia.org&lt;/a&gt;. From the case &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52525"&gt;rID: 52525&lt;/a&gt; [Accessed 15 Nov.2018].</p>
```

What do I do?

Comment: So you are trying to insert some new tags into the HTML and I assume then write the resulting HTML out? If so what is the URL you are scraping?

Comment: The url I scraped is not relevant to the question as I have already scraped it - I wrote the code for scraping the url and it works. What doesn’t work is the code to include the scraped information into the existing list, hence the question.

Comment: Having the URL would allow `soup` to be obtained and your code to be tested.

Comment: Sure, the url is specified within the scraped_ref variable above. But I use many other references, too many to specify here. My scraping code is complicated and is designed to accommodate various sites. It would only muddle the question.